# Настройка phpMyAdmin 3.4.8

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Вот поставил в папку с сайтом на локальном компютере под управлением веб-сервера Apache 2.2
систему управления MySQL - phpMyAdmin 3.4.8.
При запуске в браузере("мой_сайт.loc/phpMyAdmin") выдает форму с вводои пароля.
Какой там должен быть пароль или как его установить?
Я слышал, сто весь конфиг настрамвается в файл "config.inc.php", но в папке с phpMyAdmin
я его не нашел.
**Прошу помощи...**

Comment: пароль для доступа к бд

Comment: Я только поставил phpmyadmin и поэтому у меня еще нет ниодной базы данных и создать я её тоже не могу - не могу войти в phpmyadmin)))

Answer (score 1):

У сервера MySQL по умолчанию есть один пользователь, если вы конечно его не удалили. Имя ему root пароль по умолчанию либо пустой либо был задан вами при установке сервере.